# orderBy on hasMany relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship, has-many

I made a "hasMany" relationship from Category model to Product model using ProductCatRel model.

I am trying to ordering my products form Category model. The "where" condition is fine, But "orderBy" is not working. Here is my code:

```
public function Products(){
    return $this->hasMany(ProductCatRel::class,'category')
        ->with('Product')
        ->whereHas('Product', function($q){
            $q->where('status', 1)->orderBy('position');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet may works

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(ProductCatRel::class,'category')
        ->with('Product')
        ->whereHas('Product', function($q){
            $q->where('status', 1)
    });
}

$products = App\Category::find(1)->products()->orderBy('position')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`whereHas()` only check existence and don't affect on retrieved relation data.

You should apply `orderBy()` in `with()` method. Also you need to duplicate status checking in `with()` method.

```
public function Products(){
    return $this
        ->hasMany(ProductCatRel::class, 'category')
        ->with(['Product' => function ($q) {
            $q->where('status', 1)->orderBy('position');
        }])
        ->whereHas('Product', function($q) {
            $q->where('status', 1);
        });
}
```